# Rails: change CSS property dynamically?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, css

I have a need to change the `max-width` CSS property dynamically depending on how many images there are associated with a given model.

How can I do this w/in Rails 3.1?

*(Javascript & SASS/SCSS also at our disposal)*

Comment: Could that property be in the style of the given tag?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you can do this?

```
<div style="max-width:<%= @somemodel.images.size * X %>px"> ... </div>
```

Where `X` is a single image's width.

Alternatively, you can do

```
<div class="images count<%= @somemodel.images.size %>px"> ... </div>
```

And then have CSS rules for `div.images.count1`, `div.images.count2`, `div.images.count3` etc.. but that's not very scalable, so better stick with a `style` attribute