# How can I use Ruby/Rails variables inside Sass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

Is there a way to use variables from my Ruby application inside a Sass file?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can add .erb extention to your .sass file and then add your variables just like in regular .erb file:

```
<%= APP_CONFIG[:yourkey] %>
```

More information:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets
- http://rwilcox.tumblr.com/post/9038701675/sass-variables-and-the-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline

Comment: Be aware when doing this that Sass files are by default only compiled once and then served statically.

Comment: Yes...so it doesn't make sense to have a dynamic object accessible in a SASS/CSS file like you would in an html template.