# Accessing Rails.env inside Sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Is it possible to access Rails.env inside Sass files?

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
$url: <%= Rails.env.production? ? '//foo.com' : '//localhost:3000' %>

@font-face {
  src: url("#{$url}/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot");
}
```

But this gives:

> Invalid CSS after "$url:": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "<%= Rails.env.p..."

I've tried with different file extensions, like `css.scss.erb` etc, but no joy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Ruby/Rails variables inside SASS and LESS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653381/use-ruby-rails-variables-inside-sass-and-less)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure it is `name.css.scss.erb`

Also, here is a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7653451/643500

Comment: Thanks, your previous answer (before you edited it) helped fix this. I just used a `css.erb` extension and removed the variable.

Comment: actually, the file name should be `name.css.scss.erb`