# Can I access SASS variables from Rails classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

In my Rails 4 application I have a number of SASS variables like this one:

```
$primary_color: #ec4158;
```

Is it possible to access that variable from a Rails class somehow?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not trivially. Why would you want to? Shouldn't those variables be going the other way, since you can make a Sass file ERb, but not vice-versa?

Comment: @DaveNewton: I am using [Prawn](http://prawnpdf.org) to build a PDF and Prawn comes with its own mark up language. I would like to use my website's colour scheme in those PDFs without having to copy the values over manually.

Comment: I guess you could use the Sass parser to load them all up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make it the other way around.

1. define constants in an initializer or somewhere else ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653381/use-ruby-rails-variables-inside-sass-and-less))
2. generate your sass using erb (yourstyle.sass.erb)
3. use the same constants in your prawn generation