# can i change a sass variable based on a rails config setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I want my site to change some basic colors, when the site loads from different domains.

Right now I'm setting a bunch of configuration values in a Rails initializer as follows:

```
if `hostname` == 'example1.org'
    set_plaoul_config
elsif `hostname` == 'example2.org'
    set_gracilis_config
elsif `hostname` == 'example3.org'
    set_wodeham_config
else
    set_plaoul_config
end
```

The functions referenced here will set a variety of `Rails.application.config` settings, see the snippet below:

```
Rails.application.config.biography = true
Rails.application.config.bibliography = true
Rails.application.config.timeline = true
Rails.application.config.about = true
Rails.application.config.blog = false
```

But I'm wondering if anyone can think of a way that I can set a basic a config setting to effect a global sass variable in my sass style sheets.

For example:

```
Rails.application.config.dark-color = #BBCEBE
```

Right now /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass contains some basic theme variables, as follows:

```
* site theme colors
$dark-color:                #BBCEBE
$light-color:               #E6EDE8
$text-color:                black
$text-bgcolor:              white
```

I wish there was a way to change the values of these variables based on a config setting set when the Rails app initializes.

For example, I wish I could do this in my Sass file:

```
    $dark-color: Rails.application.config.dark-color
```

(I know that I can't do this, I'm just trying to illustrate my desired behavior)

For me the problem is I can't see a way to pass Rails information to Sass.

Ideas?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653381/use-ruby-rails-variables-inside-sass-and-less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [How can I use Ruby/Rails variables inside Sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653381/use-ruby-rails-variables-inside-sass-and-less)

Just add .erb to your sass stylesheet filename. Then use variables as normal:

```
<%= Rails.application.config.dark-color %>
```