# How do I invalidate assets in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets

I'm using Rails 3.1 and I have a `dynamic.css.scss.erb` in `app/assets/stylesheets` that generates css from the user-configurable settings. This works really well.

If these settings change, though, I'd like to invalidate the css to force a reload of the new values.

How do I do this? Or else, what other method do I use to generate the dynamic CSS?

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this answers your question but

check your config/application.rb file for the following

> ```
> # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
> config.assets.version = '1.0'
> ```

Comment: Ah, I vaguely remembered seeing something like this, thanks! In the end, I went another route, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556915/how-do-i-create-dynamic-css-in-rails/8436723#8436723